# Android: Google Map not appearing

Tags: android

I was trying a quick tutorial using google maps in Andriod

When I load my project I just get the Title and the Hello string below.I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  I copied the code when i generated the api key

The manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<application
    android:name=".MapsActivity"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestGoogleMapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:apiKey="0BEWMEhSfG1KpK8VJaPUKRS0bpcavE8rIvn3hjQ"
                 />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

**Update**
TestGoogleMapsActivity.java
    package Gibby.TestMaps;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestGoogleMapsActivity extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: And i think there is no problem in your visible code but once try to put <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> under the <application tag>

Comment: If .MapsActivity doesn't actually [subclass Application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html), remove that android:name element from the application tag.

Comment: Or rather, does what you have even compile?  Are you running a stale app in the emulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move this `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` inside application tag

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:name=".MapsActivity"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TestGoogleMapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to register your signing keys to google map api, and get an api key from there, that api need to be used in MapView parameter apiKey, you can get map api key by using following link:

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html ,
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: Right now I am using a debug key.   I already followed those steps. In  fact I copied the code it gave me exactly

Comment: Yes, Julian is right you are not setting content view to xml you have been posted here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [mobiForge: Using Google Maps in Android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)

Comment: Thanks Nitesh. That was the example I was using. I just uses-library in the wrongplace

Answer (score 0):

Your provided XML doesn't include a 'hello' string.  Therefore, you aren't really using that XML for your interface.  Edit your activity and alter its `setContentView(R.layout.whatever);` to point to the desired layout.  E.g., if that MapView XML of yours is in res/layout/mapview.xml , you should have `setContentView(R.layout.mapview);`

EDIT: ... oh, now you've provided a screenshot that suggests that you aren't using some default layout, but just haven't provided your entire layout (well, as the lack of a namespace attribute also suggests.)

Carry on.

EDIT: ... oh, and now you've shown the full XML, and you indeed aren't using it.  See my solution above.

/undelete